# Apache POI - Change row's cell format from String to Other

Tags: java, format, apache-poi, cell

Hi I'm using Apache POI in Java to read from an input txt file and paste onto xls sheet.

I pass each line from the input txt file as string to paste onto the sheet, however, all of my numbers/date fields are pasted as strings and I am struggling to change to relevant number/date format.

Below is what I am using to read my input:

```
              LinkedList<String[]> text_lines = new LinkedList<>();
              try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/input.txt"))) {
                  String sCurrentLine;
                  while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                      text_lines.add(sCurrentLine.split("\\t"));
                      }
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  }
```

Below is what I am using to paste:

```
         for(String[] line : text_lines){
            Row row = worksheet.createRow(row_num++);
            int cell_num = 0;
            for(String value : line){
                 Cell cell = row.createCell(cell_num++);
                 cell.setCellValue(value);
                 }}
```

And the below is what I have tried to change a particular cell to number format instead of string but does not work and the format of the cell is still as a string when my xls is produced

```
        String formatStr = "#,##0";
        HSSFCellStyle commaNumber = output.createCellStyle();
        HSSFDataFormat format = output.createDataFormat();
        commaNumber.setDataFormat(format.getFormat(formatStr));

        c.setCellStyle(commaNumber);
        c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
          }
```

Please can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, what exception is thrown in "c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)"?

Comment: sorry my mistake, the CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC part is not throwing exception. It creates the file but just doesn't do anything, the format on the cell is still a String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work if you can make sure that "value" contains a valid parseable String:

```
for(String value : line)
{
    Cell cell = row.createCell(cell_num++);
    cell.setCellValue(new Double(value));
    cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
}
```

EDIT
As you said your values are not always parsable, you can do this "trick".

Please note: Quick hack! You should not use Exceptions for flow control!

You can try to parse the double and if you not succeed => set the String value.

```
for(String value : line)
{
    Cell cell = row.createCell(cell_num++);
    try
    {
        cell.setCellValue(new Double(value));
        cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        cell.setCellValue(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tthink that would work perfectly if all my inputs were to be a double, but my input is a mixture of strings, numbers, dates. So I will have to change a column at a time to it's particular field

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the cell type to numeric if you set a value of a string - that's automatic. You might want to set a cell style to format the number though

Comment: Thanks everyone, Boardwish suggested code worked! :)